# Nonsmooth optimization approximation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-smooth-optimization

Say I want to minimize a real valued, nonsmooth function $f(x)$ (gradient is not defined at some minima).

Further let

$$
g(x, \epsilon)
$$

be a smooth approximation of $f(x)$ with

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \,g(x,\epsilon) = f(x) \,.
$$

Let the minimum of $g$ be a function of $\epsilon$ called $m(\epsilon)$ and lets assume the minimum actually exists.

**Question**: Is $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} m(\epsilon)$ also a minimum of $f$?

**Example**: Let $f(x) = |x|$. Then a smooth approximation with the properties described above is given by

$$
g(x, \epsilon)=\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon}\,.
$$

The minimum of $g$ is obtained at $x = 0$ and is a function of $\epsilon$ as: $m(\epsilon) = \sqrt{\epsilon}\,$.

Now taking the limit gives

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\,m(\epsilon) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\,\sqrt{\epsilon} = 0
$$

which is also the minimum of the original $f(x)$. The question is now if this is always the case.

Comment: This is exactly what Gamma converges is about.

Comment: I will take a look at gamma convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true in general. Think of the function $g(x,\epsilon) =  \epsilon x^3$. For any $\epsilon$, this function has an $\inf$ of $-\infty$. So $m(\epsilon) = -\infty$ (or not defined as this is just infimum and not the minimum). But as $\epsilon$ goes to zero, this function converges to $f(x) = 0$ which has minimum $0$.

For the case where the minimum exists, it is still not true in general. Consider the function $f(x) = 0$. Now assume $h(x)$ is a smooth function which $h(1) = h(-1) = 0$ and $h(0) = 1$ and $h(x)=0$ outside the interval $[-1,1]$. Now lets take a look at the functions $g(x,\epsilon) = -h(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})$. You can easily see that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} g(x,\epsilon) = f(x)$ for all $x$. But $m(\epsilon) = -1$ and does not converge to $\min_x f(x) = 0$.

One condition under which this would be true is when the functions $g(x,\epsilon)$ are greater than or equal to $f(x)$ for all $x$ and $\epsilon$. In that case, let's assume that $\min_x f(x) = f(x_0) = m$. Then it is obvious that $m(\epsilon)=\min_x g(x,\epsilon) \geq m$. On the other hand $m(\epsilon)\leq g(x_0,\epsilon)$. Now let's rewrite these inequalitites and take the limit  $m \leq\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}m(\epsilon)\leq \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}g(x_0,\epsilon) = f(x_0)=m$. As you can see the limit of $m(\epsilon)$ is sandwiched and is equal to $m$.

Another case in which the argument will be true is if the convergence of the family of functions is uniform over the space of $x$.

Comment: Sorry, forgot this condition that the minimum has to exist. I updated the question, is it still not true in general?

Comment: By exists, do you mean that it is attained at a point?

Comment: Yes, with that I mean that the minimum is finite. Thanks for the new example, but $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}-h(x - \frac{1}{\epsilon})$ should be undefined, right?

Comment: At any $x$ this limit is 0. Why undefined?

Comment: Hm I am not sure, I thought so because the term $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ diverges to $\infty$... but I guess thats not a problem here. Where can I find a proof that the above is true if $g(x, \epsilon) \geq f(x)$?